# How to add a `Style` string or `Hyperlink` in CloudDeploy?

Tags: output-formatting, string-manipulation, wolfram-cloud, deployment

There are two wrong code like this:

The first problem is I want to put the red string to `Title`.

```
CloudDeploy[
 FormFunction[{"x" -> "Integer"}, #x! &, 
  AppearanceRules -> <|
    "Title" -> StringTemplate["This is a ``.", 
       InsertionFunction -> (ToString[#, TraditionalForm] &)
      ][ Style["RED", Red]]
  |>], 
"myform", Permissions -> "Public"]
```

[image]

The second problem is I want to put the `Hyperlink` to `Description`.

```
CloudDeploy[
 FormFunction[{"x" -> "Integer"}, #x! &, 
  AppearanceRules -> <|
    "Title" -> StringTemplate["This is a ``", 
       InsertionFunction -> (ToString[#, TraditionalForm] &)
    ][ Hyperlink["Sample Image","http://pan.baidu.com/s/1xCeUq"]]
  |>
], "myform", Permissions -> "Public"]
```

[image]

So is this a bug or are there some method to realize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is, don't convert everything to string.

It seems that Cloud can't work with `String` representation of `Boxes` so let's use real expression instead:

```
CloudDeploy[
 FormFunction[
  {"x" -> "Integer"}, #x! &,
  AppearanceRules -> <|
    "Title" -> Row[{"This is a", Spacer@1, Style["RED", Red], "."}]
    |>
  ],
 "myform",
 Permissions -> "Public"]
```

[image]

Notice that I have put there `Spacer[1]` before `RED`, that's because `Whitespaces` are trimmed in the `Row`, I don't know why...

The same solution works for you second problem:

```
"Title" ->
 Row[{"This is a", Spacer@1, 
   Hyperlink["Sample Image", "http://pan.baidu.com/s/1xCeUq"], "."}]
```

[image]

Comment: yeah,Thanks for you help,and do you think this is a bug of `mathemtaica`?

Comment: The same thing that we cannot inupt carriage return by a "\n".Do you give a method?

Comment: @yode The same, don't use strings. Here, a `Column` might be of use.

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EmbeddedHTML.html may help here.